# Extract schema name based on current Snowflake column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, pii

I am working on a Snowflake tag and masking policy combination and was poking around to see if there is a way to dynamically extract the schema_name of the current working column.
I was not able to find anything that matched the requirement. Is it possible to extract this information? Perhaps something similar to the [SYSTEM$GET_TAG_ON_CURRENT_COLUMN('<tag_name>')](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_get_tag_on_current_column) function?
It doesn't have to extract just schema name, the result can be the Snowflake column object details like database_name, schema_name, etc.

Tried looking in snowflake documentation but could only find [current_schema()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_schema) which works only according to the current session database and not current column.

Comment: HI , you can write a function to check the schema by looking into the  information_schema.columns; view, what happens if the same column name is present in more than one schema ?